# witharrows package with vertical arrows placed in between equal signs

Tags: tikz-pgf, amsmath, tikz-arrows, aligned, witharrows

I am trying to use witharrows package to put explanations between equation lines.
When I use with arrows, the following is the result I get with the code snippet below the image.
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{witharrows}
\begin{document}
$\begin{WithArrows}
z & =(a^2-b^2)(a^2+b^2)\Arrow[tikz={bend left=0}]{because~$(x-y)(x+y)=x^2-y^2$}\\
& =a^4-b^4
\end{WithArrows}$
\end{document}
```

However, I wish to move the vertical arrow and the text to the space between the two equal signs (to minimize the lateral dimension of the equations).
Below is the image that I manually created by moving the components from the above image to show you the final result that I want.

[image]

Essentially, I wish to move the arrow nodes from the right side of the equation lines to the bottom of the first equal sign and the top of the second equal sign to put the arrow in between the two equations.

Is there any way to do this? Either using witharrows or creating my own command?
(I need to use this function a lot so the simplest method is preferred)
I am pretty new to Latex so I need some guidance.

Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could simply add a line in an align environment (the arrow could still be done with tikz if you want something fancier):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
z & =(a^2-b^2)(a^2+b^2)\\
&\,\Downarrow \text{because } (x-y)(x+y)=x^2-y^2 \\
& =a^4-b^4
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! But I have a follow-up question. If the text next to the arrow are multi-line equations that also need align*, how should I tackle this problem? Putting \begin{align*} inside \begin{align*} gives an error. Also, the length of the arrow needs to be adjusted to account for the multi-line of the equations.
Should I use tikz in this case? (I essentially wish to do exactly what witharrows does but place it in between the equal signs)

Comment: I edited the question to account for the multi-line equation next to the arrow and showed the problem I am facing. Is there a possible adjustment to the solution that you provided to account for this? (I am sorry if this has a straightforward solution. I am really new to this and I'm really stuck)

Comment: no do not edit a question  and make an answer invalid. Ask a new question.

Comment: oh, okay. I will post another question for that!